# Remote PowerShell Configuration

Tags: powershell-remoting

I have successfully created a remote PowerShell session.  I want to change the IdleTimeout in a remote powershell session.  I have run the `$pssession -IdleTimeout 18000` and receive the error it is looking for a cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

The variable $pssession is not a script, function or cmdlet so it does not take parameters.  `New-PSSessionOption` has the `-IdleTimeout` parameter.  Save the output of that to a variable and pass that to the `New-PSSession -SessionOption` parameter when the session is created.

Add whatever else you need to something like the following commands:

```
$a = New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeout 18000
$pssession = New-PSSession -SessionOption $a
```